# How to create a disk in VMware, using Python from a remote system?

Tags: python-2.7, vmware

I have a VMWare system. I want to run a python script which shall access the VMWare system via IP and want to create a New Disk.

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been to create a Virtual Machines,But creating a disk i have no clue

Answer (score 0):

```
dev_changes = []
    new_disk_kb = int(disk_size) * 1024 * 1024
    disk_spec = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec()
    disk_spec.fileOperation = "create"
    disk_spec.operation = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec.Operation.add
    disk_spec.device = vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk()
    disk_spec.device.backing = \
        vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk.FlatVer2BackingInfo()
    if disk_type == 'thin':
        disk_spec.device.backing.thinProvisioned = True
    disk_spec.device.backing.diskMode = 'persistent'
    disk_spec.device.unitNumber = unit_number
    disk_spec.device.capacityInKB = new_disk_kb
    disk_spec.device.controllerKey = controller.key
    dev_changes.append(disk_spec)
    spec.deviceChange = dev_changes
    vm.ReconfigVM_Task(spec=spec)
    print "%sGB disk added to %s" % (disk_size, vm.config.name)
```

Hope this helps